Obtaining ODE from master equation
Is there a standard way to go from a master equation (for a stochastic process) to an PDE that describes the evolution of the distribution of the process? I've seen two different derivations (see case 1 and case 2 below).
Case 1: symmetric random walk on the line
The following is a way to derive the heat equation from a random walk on the line. Let $P(x,t)$ be the probability that a random walker is at position $x$ at time $t$. We can expand the probability after a time step $\Delta t$ as
$$ 
P(x, t+ \Delta t) = \frac12 P(x- \Delta x, t) + \frac12 P(x + \Delta x, t)\,. 
$$
Denote $P = P(x,t)$. Taylor expand both sides of the above equation to get
\begin{align}
        P + \Delta t P_t &= \frac12 \left( P - \Delta x P_x + \frac12 (\Delta x)^2 P_{xx} \right) 
        \\
        &+ \frac12 \left( P + \Delta x P_x + \frac12 (\Delta x)^2 P_{xx} \right)
\end{align}
Let $\Delta t = (\Delta x)^2$. Then, rearranging gives
$$ P_t = \frac12 P_{xx} \,. $$
Case 2: a birth-death process
Now consider a situation where particles can be born with rate $\omega_1$ and die with rate $\omega_2$. Let $P(n,t)$ be the probability that there are $n$ particles at time $t$. During a time interval $\Delta t$, three things can happen; (1) a particle is born, (2) a particle dies, (3) nothing. Hence, we have the relation
\begin{align*} 
        P(n, t+ \Delta t) &= P(n-1,t)\omega_1 \Delta t 
        \\
        & + P(n+1,t) \omega_2 (n+1) \Delta t
        \\
        & + P(n,t) ( 1- \omega_1 \Delta t) (1-\omega_2 n \Delta t) 
        \\
        &+ O((\Delta t)^2)\,. 
    \end{align*}
The ODE describing the evolution of the probability distribution should be
$u_t = -\omega_2 u + \omega_1$.
I've seen a derivation in which one defines $u(t) = \sum_n P(n,t)$ over all integers, and does a change of variables so that $n+1 \rightarrow n$ and $n-1 \rightarrow n$. The derivation is in section 5.3 of these notes.
